# How do I split an array into odd and even numbers and place them into a matrix. What I did:

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

```
function evenAndOdd(array1){
    const array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    const odd = []
    const even = []
    for (let i=0; i<array1.length; i++){
        if (i%2===0){
            even.push(array1[i]);
        }else {
            odd.push(array1[i])
        }
        array1.push(odd)
        array1.unshift(even)
    }
    return array1
}
```

This is what i got from my console log
/usercode/index.js:3
const array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
^

SyntaxError: Identifier 'array1' has already been declared

I was expecting: array1 = [[2,4,6],[1,3,5]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is correct, you're defining `array` as input to your function as well as in the function body. It should be used like this:

```js
const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
const result = evenAndOdd(array1)
```

Next, your function modifies its input and returns it. I'm guessing you just want to get the result without changing the input. So we change it like so:

```js
function evenAndOdd(array1) {
    const odd = []
    const even = []
    for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 === 0) {
            even.push(array1[i]);
        } else {
            odd.push(array1[i])
        }
    }
    return [even, odd]
}
```

This runs, but the result is wrong. The output is `[ [ 1, 3, 5 ], [ 2, 4, 6 ] ]`. The reason is that you're checking whether the index is odd/even, but the check should be on the value in the input array. You can fix it like this:

```js
        if (array1[i] % 2 === 0) {
            even.push(array1[i]);
        } else {
            odd.push(array1[i])
        }
```

I would also change the name `array1` to `input` just to make it a bit more obvious what the variable represents.

Putting everything together, the code should look like this:

```js
function evenAndOdd(input) {
    const odd = []
    const even = []
    for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (input[i] % 2 === 0) {
            even.push(input[i]);
        } else {
            odd.push(input[i])
        }
    }
    return [even, odd]
}

const input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
let result = evenAndOdd(input)
console.log(result)
```

As a bonus, I would rather write it using filters on the input instead of a for loop and messing with indexes

```js
function evenAndOdd(input) {
    const odd = input.filter(x => x % 2 !== 0)
    const even = input.filter(x => x % 2 === 0)
    return [even, odd]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Also try this.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

const matrix = splitOddEven(arr);

console.log("Odd numbers:", matrix[0]);
console.log("Even numbers:", matrix[1]);

function splitOddEven(arr) {
    let odd = [];
    let even = [];

    for (let number of arr) {
        if (number % 2 === 0) {
            even.push(number);
        } else {
            odd.push(number);
        }
    }

    return [odd, even];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some logical issues in your code:

- You are redefining the input to your function
- You are appending the odd and even arrays to the input in each iteration

```js
console.log(evenAndOdd([1,2,3,4,5,6]));

function evenAndOdd(array1){
    const odd = [];
    const even = [];
    for (let i=0; i<array1.length; i++){
        if (i%2===0) {
            even.push(array1[i]);
        } else {
            odd.push(array1[i])
        }
    }
    
    return [odd, even];
}
```